# How to create tibble summarising missing imaging data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I am working with imaging data in a format similar to this:

```
   name  side  modality
   <chr> <chr> <chr>   
 1 alex  right xray    
 2 alex  left xray    
 3 brad  right xray    
 4 brad  left  xray    
 5 alex  right ct      
 6 alex  left  ct      
 7 brad  right ct      
 8 alex  right mri     
 9 brad  right mri     
10 brad  left  mri
```

Given each person is supposed to have left and right images of all modalities, it shows that Alex is missing a left MRI, Brad is missing a left CT, and Charlie (who doesn't appear in `data` at all) has all images missing. I am trying to create a summary table that shows which elements are 'present' or 'absent', given a list of
`names`(where Charlie is included). It would look something like this:

```
  name    left_xray right_xray left_ct right_ct left_mri right_mri n_absent
  <chr>   <chr>     <chr>      <chr>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>        <dbl>
1 alex    present   present    present present  absent   present          1
2 brad    present   present    absent  present  present  present          1
3 charlie absent    absent     absent  absent   absent   absent           6
```

I have used various dplyr verbs to get a list of patients with missing data for each modality, but I'm not really sure where to start with creating a summary table.

Dummy data:

```
data <- tibble(name = c('alex', 'alex', 'brad', 'brad', 'alex', 'alex', 'brad', 'alex', 'brad', 'brad'),
                        side = c('right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'right','right','left'),
                        modality = c('xray','xray','xray','xray','ct','ct','ct','mri','mri','mri'))

names <- tibble(name = c('alex', 'brad', 'charlie'))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

expand_grid(
  name = c('alex', 'brad', 'charlie'),
  modality = c("xray","ct","mri"),
  side = c("right",'left')
  ) %>% 
  left_join(
    data %>% 
      mutate(aux = "present")
  )  %>% 
  mutate(aux = replace_na(aux,"absent")) %>% 
  unite(modality_side,side,modality) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = modality_side,values_from = aux) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(n_absent = sum(c_across(-name) == "absent"))
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 8
# Rowwise: 
  name    right_xray left_xray right_ct left_ct right_mri left_mri n_absent
  <chr>   <chr>      <chr>     <chr>    <chr>   <chr>     <chr>       <int>
1 alex    present    present   present  present present   absent          1
2 brad    present    present   present  absent  present   present         1
3 charlie absent     absent    absent   absent  absent    absent          6
```

Comment: Thank you! Minor request (sorry if initial question unclear) is if this could be edited in such a way that the summary could also include names that don't exist in the data tibble at all. In this example, Charlie is in the names tibble but not the data tibble. It seems that it would be necessary for all names to have at least one image for the 'complete' verb to work.

Comment: I already create every possible combination of name, modality, and size in the expand grid part, so I did not understand your point because Charlie is not in the data. Therefore, even if the names aren't in the data, it will still works, if the names are passed in the expand_grid part

Comment: Sorry I think I must have seen an older version of  your answer without the expand_grid() part. Works great now!

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `full_join` of the present and all possible combinations of *name*, *side* and *modality*.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

full_join(df %>% mutate(grp = 1), 
    setNames(crossing(
        unique(unlist(c(df$name, Names))), unique(df$side), unique(df$modality)),
        colnames(df)) %>% mutate(grp = 2), c("name", "side", "modality")) %>%
  select(name:grp.x) %>% 
  mutate(grp.x = if_else(is.na(grp.x), "absent", "present")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=c("side", "modality"), values_from=grp.x) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(n_absent = sum(across(contains("_"), ~ .x == "absent"))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

##### Result

```
# A tibble: 3 × 8
  name    right_xray left_xray right_ct left_ct right_mri left_mri n_absent
  <chr>   <chr>      <chr>     <chr>    <chr>   <chr>     <chr>       <int>
1 alex    present    present   present  present present   absent          1
2 brad    present    present   present  absent  present   present         1
3 charlie absent     absent    absent   absent  absent    absent          6
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("alex", "alex", "brad", "brad", "alex",
"alex", "brad", "alex", "brad", "brad"), side = c("right", "left",
"right", "left", "right", "left", "right", "right", "right",
"left"), modality = c("xray", "xray", "xray", "xray", "ct", "ct",
"ct", "mri", "mri", "mri")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

Names <- structure(list(name = c("alex", "brad", "charlie")), class = c("tbl_df",
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(name = c('alex', 'alex', 'brad', 'brad', 'alex', 'alex', 'brad', 'alex', 'brad', 'brad'),
               side = c('right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'right','right','left'),
               modality = c('xray','xray','xray','xray','ct','ct','ct','mri','mri','mri'))

names <- tibble(name = c('alex', 'brad', 'charlie'))
side <- data %>% select(side) %>% unique()
modality <- data %>% select(modality) %>% unique()


data2 <- names %>% full_join(side, by=character(0)) %>% full_join(modality, by=character(0)) %>% mutate(new_col=paste0(side,'_',modality))
data3 <- data2 %>% left_join(data %>% mutate(id='present'), by=c('name','side','modality')) %>% mutate(id=ifelse(is.na(id), 'absent', id)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(c('name'), names_from = 'new_col', values_from = 'id') 

named <- names(data3)[2:6]

data4 <- data3 %>% mutate(n_absent=rowSums(.[,named]=='absent'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first concatenate the `side` and `modality` columns together, then generate a `complete` combination of it and the names. Then transform this "long" formate into a "wide" format, and calculate the number of absence.

#### Update

I've added `full_join(tmp, by = "name")` in my solution to accommodate the OP's updated request.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% mutate(tmp = paste0(side, "_", modality), 
                tmp2 = 1, 
                .keep = "unused") %>% 
  complete(name, tmp) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = tmp, values_from = tmp2) %>% 
  full_join(tmp, by = "name") %>% 
  mutate(across(-name, ~ifelse(is.na(.x), "absent", "present"))) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(n_absent = sum(c_across(-name) == "absent")) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 × 8
  name    left_ct left_mri left_xray right_ct right_…¹ right…² n_abs…³
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <int>
1 alex    present absent   present   present  present  present       1
2 brad    absent  present  present   present  present  present       1
3 charlie absent  absent   absent    absent   absent   absent        6
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹​right_mri, ²​right_xray,
#   ³​n_absent
```